# Output response from API post call - Javascript - 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script that I want to use to make a api POST call to retrieve a access token, which I would like to output. It works in postman but within my script step I get a 400 error

I can only make post call, am i making a mistake not passing any data? Fell like I'm doing something wrong with the response.*emphasized text*

### Postman

```
POST /incident/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&amp; scope=%2Fincident HTTP/1.1
Host: APM-ext
API-KEY: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
Authorization: Basic  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ee96a8af-dcfe-ffgr-8853-8ef83cd14845
```

### Script

```
var incident = NO12345;
console.log(incident)

var apiRequest = http.request({
    'endpoint': 'APM-ext',
    'path':'/incident/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=/incident',
    'API-KEY': 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx',
    'method': 'POST',
    "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});

var data = {};
var apiResponse = apiRequest.write(data);

if (apiResponse.statusCode == 200) {

    var response = JSON.parse(apiResponse.body);
    output.access_token = response.access_token;    
}
```

Expected Response (successful from postman)

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "00000044444444333333333333322222222222228888888888888885555555555555555",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "consented_on": 1599709455,
    "scope": "/incident"
}
```

Actual Response (from script)

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: APIm-Debug-Trans-Id, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-Global-Transaction-ID
< X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
< Connection: close
{ "error":"unknown" }
```

Comment: server side code issuing the response would help

Comment: I don't have that, im calling an external API

Comment: oh ... your request doesn't look like it has a host

Comment: Sorry yeah, I just took it out to post question, I should of stated

Comment: What is the library you are using to perform an http request?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript ES6

Comment: maybe there's a request header that postman is sending that your code isn't ... (I doubt any end point would require "Postman-Token" - but perhaps the "Host" header is required?

Comment: I dont see any headers, and postman wont make a difference I dont think, think its maybe in my code